# Is there another way to mark a recommended item as "Not Interested" in Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes posts are really long (in screen space, not necessarily words) to get to the bottom of, so a keyboard shortcut would be really helpful for marking the "Not Interested" box of a post. Is there an undocumented keyboard shortcut for the "Not Interested" button? If not, is there some other way to mark an item "Not Interested", without having to scroll all the way to the bottom of the item?

(Perhaps this is something doable with a Greasemonkey script.)

### (Update)

Note: I use Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly speaking a proper answer, but my solution is to hit J for the next item, then tap Up once to show the bottom bar of the previous item...

(edit) From @FireFeather: That put me onto the idea of, instead, hitting n to scroll to the next item without opening it (the bottom bar will be available).

Comment: Great idea! That put me onto the idea of, instead, hitting `n` to scroll to the next item without opening it (the bottom bar will be available). Thanks!

Comment: @Firefeather: Hang on, you've taught me something, isn't it meant to be the other way around? ;)

Comment: I guess typically it should be that way. :) Please feel free to add the info from my comment into your answer! (Of course, with the usual attribution.)

Answer (score 3):

There is [no shortcut key](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69973) for the "Not interested" option on a feed item.

You'll have to settle for installing the [Google Reader "Not Interested" Keyboard Shortcut](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/91209) extension.

After that's installed, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to your heart's discontent.

Comment: That sounds perfect. It doesn't mark the X for "Not Interested", though; that makes me wonder if it is having the intended effect. Also, Firefox's web console logs a message like `Network: POST https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?client=scroll [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 547ms]` *only* when I use the "Not Interested" link, not when I use the Shift + L keyboard shortcut. How can I be sure it really works?

Comment: Tried out the extension and it was kicking the toggle on the "Not interested" option of recommended items (X included). Not sure why you weren't able to see/get that also. @fir

Comment: @Eight: Tried it on another computer and it did the same thing; are you using the script in Greasemonkey on Firefox?

Comment: No, was using that script in Chrome. That's probably why. @fir

Comment: Added a comment that I use Firefox, to clarify.